# Gallery has stopped while cropping image in Kitkat Version

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity

Everyone,
I face an error while cropping image from gallery/camera with kitkat version only.Below or above this version code is working as charm but when i load this application to Android version 19 that cause the error message dialog and than after application gone force closed.But this application also work in genymotion emulator with Kitkat version so i can not the identify what the actual problem with real device.

So please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code in your in your onActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == PHOTO_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(this, photo);
                performCrop(tempUri);
            } else {
                performCrop(data.getData());
            }
        }

public Uri getImageUri(Activity inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
                inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Comment: what is code inside the  "getImageUri" method if can share so please.Thnks for reply

Comment: ya this is just a method, wait I will send you again.